# Function to return total data within a linkedlist C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Trying to implement a function in my linkedlist class that will return total amount of data stored within the list. i.e. linkedlist of 5, 10, 20 total would return 35.

My node class contains the getNextPtr and getData methods.

I implement a new Node and call it currentPtr and make it point to headPtr.

On compile i get: "36-request for member getNextPtr in currentPtr which is of non class type"

It's the same for 38 and 40, with 38 being the getData in currentPtr.

Not quite sure what I'm missing...

```
int LinkedList::getTotal()
{
    int total = 0;

    Node *currentPtr = headPtr;

(36)    while(currentPtr.getNextPtr() != NULL)
    {
(38)        total += currentPtr.getData();

(40)        currentPtr = currentPtr.getNextPtr();
    }

    return total;
}
```

The idea is to travel through the linked list until it reaches tailptr which will point to null, adding whatever data it encounter in to total.

Hope that makes some sense, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think your issue is with using '.' to reference members.  Your `currentPtr` is a pointer, therefore you should be using `->`, such as `while(currentPtr->getNextPtr() != NULL)`

Comment: P.S. In future questions it would be better to use comments (`//`) on lines you want to highlight so people can copy and paste your code into their environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dereference a pointer you need to use `->`, not `.`

e.g. your code becomes:

```
while(currentPtr != NULL)
{
   total += currentPtr->getData();
   currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
}
```

I also find it more natural to write `while(currentPtr)` (i.e. 'while I have a valid pointer') instead of explicitly testing for `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and to the other posts as well :)

Comment: Make sure you change the while condition to `currentPtr != NULL` instead of `currentPtr->getNextPtr() != NULL`. The way it is now, you ignore the last node of the linked list which is a bug (see my response this question)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use `->` instead of `.`

Second, your code has a minor bug. If you reach the last node, it's `next` is `NULL`, but that node still has data which you are ignoring. (Because you don't go in the while if `ptr->next == NULL`. That said, you should change the condition to `ptr != NULL`)

I suggest one of these codes:

If you have a dummy node in the beginning of the list (dummy node is a node with no data, just in the beginning of the list)

```
int LinkedList::getTotal()
{
    int total = 0;
    Node *currentPtr = headPtr->getNextPrt();
    while (currentPtr != NULL)  // or simply while (currentPtr)
    {
        total += currentPtr->getData();
        currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
    }
    return total;
}
```

And if you don't have a dummy node, it's just a little different:

```
int LinkedList::getTotal()
{
    int total = 0;
    Node *currentPtr = headPtr;
    while (currentPtr != NULL)  // or simply while (currentPtr)
    {
        total += currentPtr->getData();
        currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Good spot on the termination condition problem

Comment: Thanks a lot Shahbaz :) This helped a lot since when i was testing the code i was getting a segmentation fault, glad i came back to re-read the answers, very big help :)

Answer (score 1):

`currentPtr` is a pointer, not a class type (object). Use the `->` to access it's members, not `.`.

```
while (currentPrt->getNextPtr()) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `Node *currentPtr...` declares a pointer to Node.
When accessing member variables or functions of objects through a pointer -
as is the case here - you need to *dereference* the pointer.

In your case, this means replacing the `.` member accessor with a `->`

So your code should look like:

```
while(currentPtr->getNextPtr() != NULL)
{
    total += currentPtr->getData();

    currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
}
```